# Open a file in Xamarin Android

Tags: android, xamarin

I'm new on this website!

I'm experiencing some problem in **Xamarin Android** opening a file. I have to open a file which contains a list of foods and relative calories, split by some delimiter chars.

When I wrote this code for Xamarin iOS I didn't have any problem with the following code:

```
outputText.Text = "The selectable foods are:\n\n";
foreach (string line in File.ReadLines("Cibi.txt"))
{
    string[] cibsel = line.Split(delimiterChars);
    outputText.Text += cibsel[0] + "\n";
}
```

Of course in iOS the file was stored inside Resources folder.

But when I started to write the same code in Xamarin Android I'm starting to experiencing some errors.

**First** the program rusn into an exception because Visaul Studio can't find the path of the file (stored inside Assets folder). Then I found on Xamarin tutorial that suggested to use Streamreader.ReadLine() instead File.Readlines(), but I obtain the following error:

> Can not convert type 'char' to 'string'.

The program must only read a food and calories from a file and return, as output, only the name. How I can do this without experiencing that kind of error?

Thanks in advance!

Enrico

Answer (score 2):

The Xamarin [docs](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/resources_in_android/part_6_-_using_android_assets/) explain how to access files in Android.  Basically, you need to add the file to the Assets folder and set it's build action to `AndroidAsset`.  Then in your code you can read the file like this:

```
string line;

using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader (Assets.Open (my_file_name)))
{
    do {
      line = sr.ReadLine();

      string[] cibsel = line.Split(delimiterChars);
      outputText.Text += cibsel[0] + "\n";

    } while(line != null);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jason! Now I solved the problem for reading the file, and the program works fine. But now I have a similar problem for write on the same file, because my program also allows to update the food file. 
I used the stremwriter, using of sure the Assets.Open function, but when I debug and I try to update the file I receive the following exception:

System.ArgumentException: Can not write to stream.

I can't understand how I can solve it... Thanks a lot for the help!